# Mule 3.2 - Why am I getting this SAXParseException from XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, transformer-model

Using Mule 3.2 I am trying to build XML from inside my mule flow but I get this error
I tried a few ideas online but I keep getting this message.

```
   <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT">
    <mulexml:xslt-text>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
                <xsl:param name="numericId"/>
                <xsl:param name="name"/>
                <xsl:param name="url"/>                             
                <xsl:template match="*">            
                <Publisher>
                <numericId><xsl:value-of select="$numericId"/></numericId>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></name>
                <url><xsl:value-of select="$url"/></url>                    
                </Publisher>                    
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
    </mulexml:xslt-text>
    <mulexml:context-property key="numericId" value="#[header:SESSION:numericId]"/>
    <mulexml:context-property key="name" value="#[header:SESSION:name]"/>
    <mulexml:context-property key="url" value="#[header:SESSION:url]"/>     
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
```

ERROR:

```
******************************************************************************** Message               : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError) Code                  : MULE_ERROR-64999
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
1. Content is not allowed in prolog. (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper:-1 (null)
2. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError)   net.sf.saxon.event.Sender:308 (null)
3. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)   org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer:190 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1;
 Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: This usually happens when you have characters before the xml declaration (<?xml ...)

Comment: This seems to be a general XML question -- not an XSLT one. What is mule?

Comment: It is an XSLT one as it is a problem with the sax parser interpreting UTF8 characters. You can load it as XML fine, but if you try to process it with sax there are issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try externalizing the `xslt-text` in an XSL file to avoid interference with the XML Mule configuration.

Also you don't show how you feed the XSLT transformer: the issue is maybe upfront of it, in the data you're feeding it.

Comment: How can you access flow message properties from a java component in Mule 3.2? If I have this in my flow..  <message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="save values to session">          
            <add-message-property key="name" value="#[json-node://name]"/>     
        </message-properties-transformer>

Comment: That deserves a new question IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you have a space between the opening of the file and the xml declaration. If you don't have that, it can be caused in some situations (and I know it happens in java) if you are processing a UTF-8 file that has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) marker at the start of it.

This is incorrectly interpreted as that space. I know when I had the problem before (in java 5), I had to write a UTF8 handling input source to correct it (if you can't remove the marker).

Edit: Not just SAX, it is a java issue [bug description](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4508058)

Comment: I can not get rid of this error! Can anyone suggest an alternative way to transform a Mule Payload besides Xslt?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what mule is, but if it is this issue (as I suspect it is, the error is the same), load the file and pass it to sax stripping the bom off

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have XML in message payload before you execute XSLT transformer.
You can use for example Object-to-XML transformer before XSLT.